# Using personal number to send sms twilio,Salesforce

Tags: api, twilio

I have gone through various blogs and Twilio documentation,to use our personal number to send sms.They have mentioned ,the verified numbers can only be used to make calls.Is there any way(programmatically) we can use our personal number to send sms?I know they have a beta version toll free number which can send sms from us and canada.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to Send SMS from personal no using Twilio. But you can use **Alphanumeric Sender ID** which allows you to send Twilio Programmable SMS messages using a personalized sender name, in supported countries.

Please follow this Twilio doc [Getting Started with Alphanumeric Sender ID for Twilio Programmable SMS](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181348-Getting-started-with-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response ..I'll check that out.

Comment: hey can we programmatically register a  Alphanumeric Sender ID through apex?